# get Get property from Class in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have one method for push class property into `NameValuCollection`

```
private NameValueCollection ObjectToCollection(object objects)
{

    NameValueCollection parameter = new NameValueCollection();


    Type type = objects.GetType();

    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                    BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                                    BindingFlags.Public);
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if (property.GetValue(objects, null) == null)
        {
            parameter.Add(property.Name.ToString(), "");
        }
        else
        {
            if (property.GetValue(objects, null).ToString() != "removeProp")
            {
                parameter.Add(property.Name.ToString(), property.GetValue(objects, null).ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    return parameter;
    }
```

In my case when I pass My Model class to this method it's for correctly, but when in my Model class I use another Model like this

```
public class Brand
{
    public MetaTags MetaTag { get; set; } // <---- Problem is here

    public string BrandName { get; set; }

}

public class MetaTags
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

It's not add `MetaTag`s Class Property to the collection and just Add `MetaTag` to the collection

I want this method return this `OutPut`

```
key:Title       Value:value
key:Description Value:value
key:Language    Value:value
key:BrandName   Value:value
```

But this method return this

```
key:MetaTag     Value:
key:BrandName   Value:value
```

How I can do it ?

Comment: You need to make your function recursive.

Comment: What's the purpose of the output?  What are you doing with it that you need to use reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the recursive approach to give you the desired results:

```
    public static NameValueCollection ObjectToCollection(object objects)
    {

        NameValueCollection parameter = new NameValueCollection();


        Type type = objects.GetType();

        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                                        BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var property in CollectPropertiesIncludingNestedTypes(objects, properties))
        {
            parameter.Add(property.Item1, property.Item2);
        }

        return parameter;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> CollectPropertiesIncludingNestedTypes(object source, PropertyInfo[] properties)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (property.GetValue(source, null) == null)
            {
                yield return new Tuple<string, string>(property.Name.ToString(), "");
            }
            else
            {
                var propValue = property.GetValue(source, null);
                if (propValue.ToString() != "removeProp")
                {
                    if (!(property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || property.PropertyType == typeof(string)
                    || property.PropertyType == typeof(Guid) || property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)))
                    {
                        foreach (var val in CollectPropertiesIncludingNestedTypes(propValue, property.PropertyType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                                        BindingFlags.Public)))
                            yield return val;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        yield return new Tuple<string, string>(property.Name.ToString(), propValue.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To detect the custom types I used the primitive types check including the special types like `string`, `datetime` and `guid`. But This will give you the idea of how it can be done.

Comment: very thank's for your help